# Chart.js v3: Tooltip callback doesn't identify clicked dataset of stacked bar chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js, stacked-chart

In Chart.js v2, the datasetIndex property of ChartTooltipItem[] identifies which segment of a stacked bar chart was clicked. This allowed the tooltip content to be customized for each segment of the stacked bar chart.

In v3, TooltipItem[] provides the datasets but does not identify which one was clicked. There is a datasetIndex field for each TooltipItem, but it just matches the index in TooltipItem[] rather than identify the clicked segment.

Has anyone found a field in the V3 tooltip callback to identified which segment of a stacked bar chart was clicked? Or was this functionality lost in the v3 rewrite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just works fine, the only thing that is different is that it seems like in v2 it defaulted to the `point` mode while now it is using `index` mode, if you change it back to `point` it works as expected:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: 'red'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        backgroundColor: 'blue'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        mode: 'point',
        callbacks: {
          beforeBody: (ttItems, x) => {
            ttItems.forEach((ttItem) => {
              console.log('BeforeBody: ', ttItem.datasetIndex, ttItem.dataIndex)
            })
          },
          afterBody: (ttItems, x) => {
            ttItems.forEach((ttItem) => {
              console.log('AfterBody: ', ttItem.datasetIndex, ttItem.dataIndex)
            })
          }
        }
      }
    },
    scales: {
      y: {
        stacked: true
      },
      x: {
        stacked: true
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.4.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, LeeLenalee!!! This resolved the issue.

Comment: This is also the case for horizontal bar in v3.